# The UWP app does not work in "BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached" mode, it only works in "BluetoothCacheMode.Cached" mode, why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using this code-->https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario2_Client.xaml.cson "Blue Gecko bgm13p22" microcontroller BLE device to read its services and characterstics. If I use "BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached" mode it says "Device Unreachable" but when I use "BluetoothCacheMode.Cached" mode it shows already stored characterstics or services, but not in real time.

Why is this happening?

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You say "already stored characteristics or services", so I presume you have successfully read them at least once. They have been saved in the Bluetooth Cache.

In your instance, using `BluetoothCacheMode.Cached` **doesn't connect to the device** to look for characteristics - it looks in the Bluetooth cache, that's why it doesn't show them "real time". Using `BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached` attempts a connection and it fails.

With "Device Unreachable" as a response, the first thing to try is to refresh the device object.

```
    BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId); 
    .....
```